# Using Enum as string in PHP with PhpStan

Tags: php, symfony, enums, static-analysis, phpstan

I'm experimenting with PHP enums in a Symfony 6 application and I thought I found a very nice use case for those. Everything works, but phpstan keeps complaining about the type I return.

```
 ------ -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Line   src/Entity/User.php
 ------ -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  93     Return type (array<App\Security\Roles>) of method App\Entity\User::getRoles() should be compatible with return type (array<string>) of method
         Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getRoles()
 ------ -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Enum looks like this:

```
namespace App\Security;

enum Roles: string
{
    case Admin = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
    case User = 'ROLE_USER';
}
```

In my `User` entity which implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`, I have this:

```
/**
 * @see UserInterface
 * @return array<Roles>
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = Roles::User->value;

    return array_unique($roles);
}

/**
 * @param array<Roles> $roles
 */
public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}
```

I understand that phpstan expects the array to contain a string as defined in the interface,

```
/**
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getRoles(): array;
```

But is there a way to work around this? I would really prefer to be able to leverage an Enum. Isn't the point of adding a type to the enum being able to use it as that type? Also worth mentioning that I use strict types everywhere and everything works except for phpstan being not too happy with my type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your return annotation is wrong, as PhpStan is correctly reporting.

You say you report an array of roles:

```
/**
 *  @return array<Roles>
 */
```

If that were the case, `roles` would contain an enum directly, not the value of a backed enum:

```
$this->roles[] = Roles::Admin
```

By keeping the wrong annotation, you are not only upsetting PhpStan, but you give the wrong information to consumers of `getRoles()`. The annotation you have means that I should be able to do:

```
/** @var <array>Roles */
$roles = $user->getRoles();

foreach ($roles as $role) {
   if ($role === Roles::Admin) {
       // something
   }
}
```

But you are actually returning `string[]`, not `Roles[]`, so my code wouldn't work and my application would crash. Sadness througout the land.

Without seeing additional code, it does not look you are really "using enums" in a way different from class constants. `roles` is not a collection of `Roles`, your `addRole()` metod would take a `string`, not a `Roles`, etc.

Which is perfectly fine, of course. Since you need to comply with the `UserInterface`, maybe a class with some constants would be a be a better fit here.

```
/**
 *  @return array<Roles::ROLE_*>
 */
```

A naive example of this annotation working would be:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

abstract class Roles {
    const ROLE_FOO = 'foo';
    const ROLE_BAR = 'bar';
    const ROLE_BAZ = 'baz';
}

/**
 * @param array<Roles::*> $s
 */
function sayHello(array $s): void
    {
        foreach ($s as $si) {
            echo 'Hello, ' . $si, "\n";
        }
    }

$array = [
    Roles::ROLE_FOO,
    Roles::ROLE_BAR
];

sayHello($array);

$badArray = [
    Roles::ROLE_FOO,
    'some'
];

// this is an error!
sayHello($badArray);
```

([playground link](https://phpstan.org/r/7b5b06e1-a0d4-49d5-a76d-f1b9d8cea870))

If you want to use Enums for your roles, then actually use them. But you won't be able to use them directly in  `getRoles()` because it would break the interface.

You could have a companion set of methods (`getRealRoles()`, `addRealRole(Roles $role)`, etc), wich would deal with the `roles` property, and you'd leave `getRoles()` simply to convert the `array<Roles>` into an `array<string>`.

No, you wouldn't be able to express "`getRoles` returns an array comprised of elments that are the possible backed values of the `Roles` enum", but it's fine, because in *your* (as opposed to framework code, which does not care about your implementation) code you would use the methods that work with the enums.